# QGIS - Creating a batch of drawings by automatically swapping layers

Tags: qgis, layouts

I have a project where I need to create several drawings showing model results in QGIS. I have 60 drawings to create where everything is the same apart from the model results themselves and also the drawing title.

I have anonymized these maps as an example, both show model results of flooding on a river and in this example the results are polygons and the drawing title changes. I need to do something similar, 60+ times, where only the results and drawing title change.

[image: Flood 1]

[image: Flood 2]

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "drawing"?

Comment: Sorry, an exported layout to be included in a report

Comment: Perhaps you can post two example "drawings". Might make it a bit more clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mark could you be talking about maps?

Comment: I have anonymized these maps as an example, both show model results of flooding on a river and in this example the results are polygons and the drawing title changes.
I need to do something similar, 60+ times, where only the results and drawing title change. 
https://imgur.com/vLfjpYt

https://imgur.com/js1fok7

Sorry, not sure how to add the images.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the Atlas feature. There's a tutorial here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html#ls-creating-detailed-maps-with-the-atlas-tool

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at Atlas. I thought this was similar to data-driven pages in Arc and just moved the area to be printed. I'll take a look at that tutorial now.

Comment: Yeah, I've taken a look at Atlas and as expected this creates a number of detailed maps of an area, for example following a route corridor (similar to data-driven pages). Sadly this isn't what I want, I need to automatically switch layers on and off. Any more ideas?